# Cómo eliminar totalmente un elemento de html mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos `<form>` una es para loguearse y otras es para registrarse. La `<form>` para el registro (`#registro-forma`) tiene un link abajo en el que si se pincha se debería cargar la `<form>` login (`#login-forma`)

Sin embargo no aparece bien, se ve sólo la mitad de la forma. Cuando la pongo sola si aparece bien.

```js
document.getElementById("loginclick").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("registro-forma").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login-forma").style.display = "inline";
  });
```

```css
#login-forma{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
 <!--FORM REGISTRO:-->
      <div id="registro-forma">
          <h3 id="registro-title">Comienza a Entrenar</h3>
          <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
              Nombre de Usuario:
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
                  <label for="disabled"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              Contraseña:
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                  <label for="password"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              Email:
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                  <label for="email"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-submit" type="submit" name="action">ENVIAR
                <i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>
              </button>
              <p>¿Ya estas registrado? <a id="loginclick" href="#" onclick="openLogin()">Logéate</a></p>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

       <!--FORM LOGIN:-->
    <div id="login-forma">
        <h3 id="registro-title">Entra con tu cuenta</h3>
                    <div class="row">
                            <form class="col s12">
                             Nombre de Usuario:
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                  <input id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
                                  <label for="disabled"></label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              Contraseña:
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                  <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                                  <label for="password"></label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-submit" type="submit" name="action">ENVIAR
                                <i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>
                              </button>
                              <p>¿No estas registrado? <a id="loginregister" href="#" onclick="openRegister()">Regístrate</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>   
          <div>
```

He pensado si es algun problema con el código de estilos que tengo para el vídeo que va sobre estas dos formas y que este obligando a los estilos de las formas a hacer algo raro, pero el caso es que lo he probado en jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wuez4bpv/ y aquí si se muestran ambas bien por lo que ni idea, y se me ha ocurrido si hay alguna forma de eliminar totalmente una de las form para que así se pueda visualizar bien (pero luego se pueda recuperar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**En JS puro:**

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Siendo `element` tu nodo a eliminar

**En JQuery**

```
$("#element").remove();
```

Siendo `element` el `id` tu nodo a eliminar

---

**Edito por tu comentario**

Para hacerlo visible/invisible:

```
$("#element").toggle();
```

Para hacerlo visible:

```
$("#element").show();
```

Para hacerlo invisible:

```
$("#element").hide();
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, hay alguna manera de recuperarlo luego? Mi intención es usarlo como un "toggle", es decir, en vez de cambiar abrir y cerrar visibilidad ya que asi no me funciona, eliminar y crear.